# TCL string toupper (each word)

Tags: string, list, tcl

I have a snippet of code that I use for a program that I have [Thus some of the app specific code] ...Anyway I am trying to capitalize the first letter of each word unless the word is in caps.

for example: >>***this is text THAT would be CHANGED.***

The code that i have thus far is as follows.

**Again some of this is app specific I am not able to use "puts," the result has to be returned as  *return ""* this is the reason that I create a var and add to it word by word.**

```
proc ToTitle {} {
set Input [sh_set clipboard]
set CleanedInput [string map {" " |} [string trimright [string trimleft $Input]]]
set InputList [split $CleanedInput "|"]
set wresult ""
set item 0
foreach line $InputList {
set List_Item [lindex $InputList $item];
if {[string is upper $List_Item] == 1} {
 set newline $List_Item
    set wresult "$wresult $newline"
    incr item   
} else {
 set newline [string totitle $List_Item]
    set wresult "$wresult $newline"
    incr item
}
}
regsub -all {\u0020{2,}} $wresult " " wresult; #REMOVE ALL EXCESSIVE SPACE CHARACTERS
set $wresult [string trimright [string trimleft $wresult]]; # TRIM ALL OF THE WHITESPACE BEFORE AND AFTER THE STRING
return "$wresult"}
```

This is currently working the output would be: 
**This Is Text THAT Would Be Changed.**

The issue is the ***"Changed."*** because of the ***"."***
The question is What can I use to only read the word character on items that have special characters or word characters?

```
{[string is upper $List_Item] == 1}
```

I know there is something that I can add to that to check it...
Thankyou in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a simpler solution. Try this:

```
set a "this is text THAT would be CHANGED."
set out ""
foreach word $a {
append out "[string toupper $word 0 0] "
}
puts $out
```

Running it gives this output:

```
% % % This Is Text THAT Would Be CHANGED.
```

Comment: That worked great! Just for my understanding what is the "0" "0" at the end of `[string toupper $word 0 0]` is that the word index?

Comment: @CK1 It's the range of the string (char at index `0` — the start — to char at index `0`) to apply the toupper operation to.